# How do I add a field and value to an array in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

```
{_id: 'FAMIA',
    CUSTOMER:
        { 'customer code': FAMIA',
          'customer name': 'Familia Arquibaldo',   
         submits:
            [ { ORDER:
               { 'order id': 666
                 'employee id': 6 }}]}}
```

So basically like the code above, I want to add fields such as 'order id': 666 or 'employee id': 6 to an array 'submits' below:

```js
{_id: 'FISSA',
    CUSTOMER:
        { 'customer code': FISSA',
          'customer name': 'FISSA Fabrica',   
         submits:[] } }
```

What I have tried so far:

```
db.customers.updateOne({_id: "FISSA"}, {$set: {"submits.ORDER.orderid":999}})
```

Output:

```
{_id: 'FISSA',
    CUSTOMER:
        { 'customer code': FISSA',
          'customer name': 'FISSA Fabrica',   
         submits:[] },
      submits: {ORDER: { orderid: 999 }}}
```

Why is there an extra submits field? I want to simply insert into the first submits[] array, an ORDER field, and an order id field in it, but not a duplicate submit field.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a screenshot of what output must look like?

Comment: my apologies guys, hopefully the formatting is better now

Comment: Can you please show your command? In your question it is not clear what is the input data and what is the expected result.

Comment: Thanks @WernfriedDomscheit. I was referring to the end result* and not the original documents. Will ask for text hereafter :)

Comment: sorry for the lack of info/detail, i have updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like to add an element to an array then you need [$push](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/update/push/). Try this one (not tested)

```
db.collection.updateOne(
   { _id: 'FISSA' },
   { $push: { "CUSTOMER.submits": {orderid: 999} } }
)
```